# angular javascript timepicker

Tags: javascript, timepicker

hi I would like to give users the possibility to insert in a timepicker input field the time like this : 06.55 , I would like to give users the possibility to use . (the point) instead of : (double point) any solution? thanx

Comment: Do you use a library for the timepicker or did you code it yourself? Some of your code would help to solve the problem.

Comment: i'm using moment library